# How to count amenities per admin_level n in a foreach loop over admin_level n+2 with overpy

Tags: python, overpass-api

I would like to count amenities (bars and pubs) per admin_level 6 (departement) with overpy.

I succeeded to make a csv file with overpass turbo :

```
[out:csv(id, total )];
//All French départements (level 6) from FR-01 to FR-95 plus FR-2A and FR-2B
area[admin_level=6]["ISO3166-2"~"^FR-[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-5]|2[A-B]"];

// Counts  bars and pubs in each dpt (level 6)
foreach->.dpt(
  // search for bars and pubs
  (
    way(area.dpt)[amenity=pub];
    way(area.dpt)[amenity=bar];
    node(area.dpt)[amenity=pub];
    node(area.dpt)[amenity=bar];
  );

  make count id = dpt.set(t["ref"]),
             total = count(ways) + count(nodes);
  out;
);
```

but since I understood that overpy doesn't deal with csv files, I would like to get a list of couples (area ref, number of bars and pubs).

This :

```
import overpy

api = overpy.Overpass()

dpts = api.query("""
// All french departements (level 6)
area[admin_level=6]["ISO3166-2"~"^FR-[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-5]|2[A-B]"];

// Find bars and pubs in each dpt
foreach->.dpt(
  // looks for bars and pubs
  (
    way(area.dpt)[amenity=pub];
    way(area.dpt)[amenity=bar];
    node(area.dpt)[amenity=pub];
    node(area.dpt)[amenity=bar];
  );
  out;
);
""")
```

gives me all the nodes and ways but not sorted by area.dept.

I got all the bars and pubs :

```
In [102]: len(dpts.ways + dpts.nodes)
Out[102]: 3895
```

How could I get a list of type `[(area ref, number of pubs and bars)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it is easy to use Python to loop :

```
Bars = []
api = overpy.Overpass()
for d in range(21,96):
    dpt = api.query("""
    area[admin_level=6]["ISO3166-2" = "FR-{}"];
    (way(area)[amenity=bar];
    node(area)[amenity=bar];);
    (._;>;);
    out;""".format(d))
    Bars.append((d, len(dpt.ways + dpt.nodes)))
Bars
```

But that creates a query each time. Is it less efficient than looping inside the query ?

Comment: Did something similar just now but you will soon get a `OverpassTooManyRequests: Too many requests` error for this behaviour. :/